# Differential Equation of $y'=y\sin(2x)+\sin(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation:

$$y'=y\sin(2x)+\sin(2x)$$

First I solve homogenous case where $$y=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)}$$ but I don't know how to solve as it is non-homogenous.

Comment: It is separable, $y'=(y+1)\sin(2x)$.

Comment: You can separate variables and then integrate

Answer (score 3):

It is easier by separated variables:

$\frac{y^\prime}{y+1}=\sin(2x)$. Then $\log|y+1|=-\frac{\cos 2x}{2}+C$